# Cannot route traffic between 2 networks

Tags: networking, routing, gateway

```
>C:\>netstat -r

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.125.75.1      10.125.75.2    281
       10.125.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link       10.125.75.2     26
      10.125.75.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.125.75.2    281
   10.125.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.125.75.2    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.2     26
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.0.2    281
      192.168.0.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.2    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.2    281
  192.168.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.2    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.125.75.2    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.2    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.125.75.2    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.2    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.125.75.1  Default
       10.125.0.0      255.255.0.0      10.125.75.2       1
      192.168.0.0      255.255.0.0      192.168.0.2       1
===========================================================================
```

Window vista PC

2 network cards in same workstation

```
NIC 1 
IP  10.125.75.2 
SNM 255.255.255.0
GW  10.125.75.1 routes traffic to ADSL router then to internet 

NIC 2 
IP  192.168.0.2 
SNM 255.255.255.0
GW  00.00.00.00  so as not to get that multi gateway issue
```

Hello I am having problems routing TCP IP traffic

The only succesful pings are due to the network cards NIC 1 & NIC 2 residing in the same workstation.
10.125.75.2 pc can ping the network card 192.168.0.2 and vice versa.

Workstations on the 10.125.75.X network can only ping the 10.125.75.2 network card but cannot ping the 192.168.0.2 network card

And again Workstations on the 192.168.0.X network can only ping the 192.168.0.2 network card but cannot ping the 10.125.75.2 network card

I have tried to add the following persistent routes but it is not working

```
route -p add 10.125.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 125.125.75.2 
route -p add 192/168.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 192.168.0.2
```

But the routes added are not allowing pings to resolve the above issues.

**My question(s) is /are:**

What amendments do I need to make to routing table (delete entries, if any that are allowing traffic not to route )

What are the correct route commands I need to add in order for the networks to route traffic

Currently only 10.125.75.X workstations can access the internet,it is possible to add a route that will also 
allow trafic from the 192.168.0.2  to jump onto the 10.125.0.0 network then also allow traffic to  go to the internet

Answer (score 0):

What you need cannot be done just by playing with routes - you need a service that would listen on one side and pass the packets to the other.

In Windows it's called RRAS, but that's available only on server versions.
If you don't have one I think you can configure a bridge between the to interfaces, and that should do it.